# Why I can't see all HTTP requests from Charles? (Android)

Tags: android, http, debugging, proxy, charles-proxy

I try to intercept requests from a game one Android. I used Charles web debugging proxy and Proxydroid for that. But the problem is I can't see all HTTP requests, I'm obliged to use Wireshark...

Here's an example of requests I can see with Wireshark but not with Charles:

```
-493    113.929840  10.8.0.1    23.91.97.104    HTTP    422 POST /rl_w_shopbuy HTTP/1.1  (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)-
POST /rl_r_shoplist HTTP/1.1
Host: 23.91.97.104:8080
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Length: 178
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Uid=1608871039&Cmd=1701&Packageid=1&Count=1&Uid=1608871039&Session=3A4191B7A934129E798C64ABE486D1CF&Clinettime=2015/06/08 07:03:21 Monday&Platform=android&Version=13.0&Pt=1062&ServerID=749&GroupID=2

-495    115.440400  23.91.97.104    10.8.0.1    HTTP/XML    502 HTTP/1.1 200 OK-
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.5.2
Date: Mon, 08 Jun 2015 05:03:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: 0
Content-Encoding: gzip

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RENLONG code="0" msg=""><shopbuy costyb="0" costyz="2800"></shopbuy>
<retobj type="2" id="100015" count="10"></retobj>
<bagid bagid="52|53|54|55|56|57|77|80|81|91"></bagid>
<attr attr="4|5|5|4|1|4|4|1|2|4"></attr>
```

Comment: did you install the charless ssl certifate ?

are your phone and laptop conntected to the same network ?

check if port number and ip address are configured correctly on your phone ?

Comment: Yes, the Charles's certificate is installed and the phone and the laptop are connected to the same network.